# Overlay shapefile on multiband raster using ggRGB and ggplot2 in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot2 to map a polygon feature class over a raster brick (created from multiple Landsat band images). I'm able to map the polygons and the raster separately, but when I try to have them together (following the last code chunk at http://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/rstbx-docu/ggRGB.html RStudio crashes (even after restarting the computer).

ggRGB attempt:

```
fallowFields <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn = fgdb, layer = 'Fallowing2018')
fallowFieldsWGS84 <- spTransform(fallowFields, crs(L8_20180420_brick))

fallowFieldsDataFrame <- fallowFieldsWGS %>% fortify

landsatAprilCropped <- raster::crop(L8_20180420_brick, raster::extent(fallowFields))

p <- ggplot()
p + ggRGB(img = landsatAprilCropped,
          r = 3,
          g = 2,
          b = 1,
          stretch = 'hist',
          ggLayer = TRUE) +
geom_polygon(col = 'Black',
             fill = 'grey70',
             data = fallowFieldsDataFrame,
             aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
```

replacing the data frame (fallowFieldsDataFrame) with the shapefile (fallowFieldsWGS84) works, but it warps the Landsat image.

[image]

The cropped image and shapefile are in the same projection, but the shapefile seems to be warping the raster. **Is there a way to plot the shapefile over the raster without warping it?**

[image]

[image]

It doesn't get warped with plotRGB, but I was hoping to use ggRGB so that I could make a more elegant map with gglot2.

[image]

```
plotRGB(landsatAprilCropped, 
        r = 3, g = 2, b = 1, 
        stretch = 'hist', axes = TRUE,
        main = 'Fallow Fields Overlaid on Landsat Image: 4/20/2018')

plot(bardFallowFields, col = 'transparent', border = 'red', add = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss a very important part. First, an example:

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(RStoolbox)

data(lsat)

lsat

poly <- as(extent(622999,625000,-417000,-415000),'SpatialPolygons')

poly <- fortify(poly)

names(poly)[1:2] <- c('x','y')

e <- extent(lsat)


p <- ggplot() + ggRGB(img = lsat,
            r = 3,
            g = 2,
            b = 1,
            stretch = 'hist',
            ggLayer = T) + 
  xlim(e[1:2]) + ylim(e[3:4]) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x,y), alpha = 0.9, data = poly)
```

Using `ggRBG()` output is:

```
ggRGB(img = lsat,
      r = 3,
      g = 2,
      b = 1,
      stretch = 'hist')
```

[image]

With your procedure I reproduced the same issue:

```
p
```

[image]

The solution is to add **`coord_equal()`**

```
p + coord_equal()
```

[image]

**I recomend you to add `ylim()` and `xlim()` with the extent of raster object**